# Shopping Cart Error (LaravelShoppingcart)

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart, laravel-5

I am using `Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart` with Laravel 5. When I try to add items to Cart then it will display error

> Non-static method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Any help for resolve this..

Comment: Can you add your code.

Answer (score 5):

Add this line at the top of your PHP file:

```
use Cart;
```

instead of this:

```
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart;
```

Comment: How To change TaxRate

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the facade, you're trying to call the add method statically on the actual Cart class.

So don't do use `Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart;` but `use Cart`; or
`use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;`.